# Tilemap array: Find unique contiguous elements

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

Imagine you are working for a local government as a land surveyor. It is your job to find out how much more space there is on the city's current industrial site for new buildings. To that end, you need to measure how many buildings there are today.
The industrial site is represented by a 2D array, where "B" represents (part of) a building and "E" represents an empty space. If B's are horizontally or vertically connected to other B's, then those B's are part of one building. If two B's are only diagonally connected, regard them as separate buildings.
Write a function:
find_building( input_map )
that returns the number of buildings on the industrial site.
If any of the elements in the array are not "B" or "E", the function should return -1.
Note: the initial code in the editor uses tabs for indentation. Don't mix it with spaces.
Examples:
There are three buildings in the following example:

```
[
  ["B", "B", "B"],
  ["B", "E", "B"], 
  ["E", "E", "E"], 
  ["E", "E", "B"], 
  ["B", "E", "B"]
]
```

- 

```
def func(test):
    print(test)
    count = 1
    for i in range(len(test)):
        for j, data in enumerate(test[i]):
            if data == "B" or data == "N": 
                if data == "B":
                    arr[i][j] = count;
                    count = count + 1
                if (j + 1) < len(arr[i]):
                    if arr[i][j+1] == "B" :
                        arr[i][j+1] = "N"
                if (i+1) < len(test):
                    if arr[i+1][j] == "B":
                        arr[i+1][j] = "N"

    return test
```

I want know how many buildings are there in the site. I couldn't find how to implement the exact logic.
[image]

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Your posted code defines a function and quits without calling it.

Comment: See this lovely reference for [debugging help](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs).  You show no effort to test or trace the operation of your code.  You haven't explained how it's supposed to work, it will crash due to `arr` being undefined, and you don't explain quite how it relates to the given assignment.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking for help with, but you should be aware that your algorithm won't work for upwards or leftwards facing U shaped buildings (the example in your data is downward faceing, which your code will identify correctly). Try testing with `[['B', 'E', 'B'], ['B', 'B', 'B']]`.

Answer (score 1):

Not pretty but it's working:
https://trinket.io/python3/c26252b88a

```
arr = [
  ["B", "B", "B"],
  ["B", "E", "B"], 
  ["E", "E", "E"], 
  ["E", "E", "B"], 
  ["B", "E", "B"]
]


def check_contiguous( idxRow, idxCol):
    arr[idxRow][idxCol] = 'X'
    # bottom left cell
    if idxRow == len(arr)-1 and idxCol == len(arr[0])-1:
        return 0

    # bottom row
    elif idxRow == len(arr)-1:  
        if arr[idxRow][idxCol+1] != 'B':
            return 0
        else:
            if arr[idxRow][idxCol+1] == 'B':
                check_contiguous(idxRow, idxCol+1)
    # right column
    if idxCol == len(arr[0])-1:
        if arr[idxRow+1][idxCol] != 'B':
            return 0
        else:
            if arr[idxRow+1][idxCol] == 'B':
                check_contiguous(idxRow+1, idxCol)
    else:
        if arr[idxRow+1][idxCol+1] != 'B' and \
            arr[idxRow][idxCol+1] != 'B':
            return 0
        else:
            if arr[idxRow+1][idxCol] == 'B':
                check_contiguous(idxRow+1, idxCol)
            if arr[idxRow][idxCol+1] == 'B':
                check_contiguous(idxRow, idxCol+1)

def func():
    total_nb = 0
    for idx_row, row in enumerate(arr):
        for idx_col, el in enumerate(row):
            if el == 'B':
                total_nb += 1
                check_contiguous(idx_row, idx_col)
    return total_nb

print(func())
```